# Windows FileOpenDialog returning wrong path

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, com

I want to have a simple file dialog in which the user can select a folder like the following.

[image]

When executing the following code snippet on Windows 10 build with the current Visual Studio 2017, I run into a weird problem. What I do

1. create a new folder within the opened filedialog
2. type in a new name for the folder
3. while the text cursor is still visible for the new folder, I click on "Select Folder".
4. Instead of the name I typed in for the selected folder, pszFilePath is "New folder".

Instead I would expect the Dialog to first remove the focus from the new folder when I click on "Select Folder" and then I need a second click, to actually select the folder.

Strangely enough this doesn't happen on all Windows 10 systems I tested this code on. Sometimes I can't reproduce the issue.

Anyone with the same problem and maybe a workaround?

```
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <windows.h>

void winOpenFileDialog ()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx (NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog* pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance (CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IFileOpenDialog,
            reinterpret_cast<void**> (&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
        {
            pFileOpen->SetOptions (FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show (NULL);

            FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS opt;
            pFileOpen->GetOptions (&opt);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
            {
                IShellItem* pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult (&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName (SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
                    {
                        MessageBox (NULL, pszFilePath, L"File Path", MB_OK);
                        CoTaskMemFree (pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release ();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release ();
        }
        CoUninitialize ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you're doing in Step 2? Are you in the folder text box when you're setting the new name or are you in the multi-column grid above, with the cursor on the New Folder folder?

Comment: This makes sense. Clicking on the "Select Folder" button while the folder name is still being edited will not apply the new name in time for the dialog to grab it. So the folder really is still named "New Folder" when the dialog is closed. That is not something you can address in your code, nor should you try. That is something that needs to be addressed by Microsoft in the dialog itself. File a bug report with Microsoft and move on. How often do you expect your users to edit folders inside an Open dialog?

Comment: Testing the file dialog we went into it first try.

Comment: ..or more specifically I expect the users often to create new folder and name them then.

Comment: I second Remy's comment. When you try to fix this behaviour in *your* code, you risk running into problems when MS changes the behaviour, possibly making it worse than before.

Comment: It's a Windows issue. Workaround it at your peril.